# Problems with sqlcmd -q and quotations marks

Tags: sql-server, index, sqlcmd, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition. Because it is only an Express edition I don't have a SQL Server Agent for automation of tasks.

So I tried to do something with command line program `sqlcmd`.

I try to execute this command:

```
use DB; EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?', ' ', 80)";
```

If I do this in SQL Server Management Studio everything works fine. But if I try to execute this via `sqlcmd` it doesn't work.

```
sqlcmd -S .\INSTANCE -Q "use DB; EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?', ' ', 80)";" -o C:\FOLDER\LOG_DB_REINDEX.txt
```

I think this is because of the quotation marks. I also tried to use ` and ' but I didn't get it to work...

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use this. ;-)

```
use DB; EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1=N'print ''?'' DBCC DBREINDEX (''?'', '' '', 80) ';
```

Double quotation marks will escape the following quotation mark.

Here an example of sqlcmd:

```
sqlcmd -S YOURSERVER -Q "use net_temp_test; EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1=N'print ''?''';"
```

Comment: thank you for this easy and quick answer! works fine! :-)

Comment: Nice to help you :-)